# Como puedo modificar los datos ya asignados en un array por medio de su id

Tags: java

Tengo que modificar los datos del array "jugadores" que son nombre, apellido, dorsal, posición, edad, equipo. que posteriormente fueron ingresados por el usuario

lo que se pide es que el usuario ingrese el id del jugador que quiere modificar, y modificar los datos.

y si el jugador no existe notificarlo.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda

Aca el codigo

```
package convocar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Convocar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int contador = 0;
        int opcion;
        
        Jugador [] jugadores = new Jugador[5];

            do{

            System.out.println("1. Agregar un Jugador");
            System.out.println("2. Mostar un Jugador");
            System.out.println("3. Editar un Jugador");
            System.out.println("4. Mostrar todad la convocatoria");
            System.out.println("5. Salir");
            
            System.out.println("Digite una opcion");
            opcion = entrada.nextInt();
            
            switch(opcion){          
                    
                case 1:
                   System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador a modificar");
                    int idSearch = entrada.nextInt();
                    for (int i=0; i<jugadores;i++) {
                           if (idSearch == jugadores[i]) {
                            jugadores.setNombre();
                        }                    
                    }                      
                    break;            
                case 2:
                      System.exit(0);               
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                    break;
            }         
        }while(opcion != 4); 
}
```

Comment: El código que has puesto no tiene sentido alguno. No puedes tener el main y en la primera línea un `case`, porque no hay switch delante. Por favor pon todo el código necesario para que tu ejemplo sea un [mre]!

Comment: En tu class `Jugador` tienes el atributo `id` imagino verdad?

Comment: si claro que esta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes como debería de verse tu código :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Jugador {
    int id;
    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    int dorsal;
    int posicion;
    int edad;
    String equipo;
    
    Jugador() {
        
    }
    
    Jugador (int i, String n, String a, int d, int p, int e, String eq) {
        this.id = i;
        this.nombre=n;
        this.apellido = a;
        this.dorsal = d;
        this.posicion = p;
        this.edad = e;
        this.equipo = eq;
    }
}
public class Convocar {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int contador = 0;
        int opcion = -1;
        
        Jugador[] jugadores = {new Jugador(1,"Alex","APELLIDO",1,2,3,"a")};
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador a modificar");
            int idSearch = entrada.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i<jugadores.length; i++) {
                if (jugadores[i].id == idSearch) {
                    jugadores[i].id = 5;
                    jugadores[i].nombre = "NUEVONOMBRE";
                    jugadores[i].apellido = "NUEVOAPELLIDO";
                    jugadores[i].dorsal = 20;
                    jugadores[i].edad = 20;
                    jugadores[i].equipo = "NUEVOEQUIPO";
                    jugadores[i].posicion = 10;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
            break;
        }while(opcion!=4);
    }
}
```

En este caso ya me he creado yo mismo mi propia clase `Jugador` con los atributos que tu tienes. Hemos añadido un jugador :
`Jugador[] jugadores = {new Jugador(1,"Alex","APELLIDO",1,2,3,"a")};`

Y principalmente, el código que necesitas para actualizar los valores del array del objeto `Jugador` es el siguiente código en la instrucción `case 1:`

```
for (int i = 0; i<jugadores.length; i++) {
                if (jugadores[i].id == idSearch) {
                    jugadores[i].id = 5;
                    jugadores[i].nombre = "NUEVONOMBRE";
                    jugadores[i].apellido = "NUEVOAPELLIDO";
                    jugadores[i].dorsal = 20;
                    jugadores[i].edad = 20;
                    jugadores[i].equipo = "NUEVOEQUIPO";
                    jugadores[i].posicion = 10;
                }
            }
```

Si el `ID entrado por teclado` coincide se cambian los atributos del `indice` donde nos encontramos en el array.
En caso de no querer ir escribiendo los valores (`jugadores[i].nombre=="ALGO"`) puedes crear variables para asignar los valores, esto te será más comodo.

***Ejemplo***

```
case 1:
            System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador a modificar");
            int idSearch = entrada.nextInt();

            int nuevoID = 10;
            String nombre = "NUEVONOMBRE";
            String apellido = "NUEVOAPELLIDO";
            for (int i = 0; i<jugadores.length; i++) {
                if (jugadores[i].id == idSearch) {
                    jugadores[i].id = nuevoID;
                    jugadores[i].nombre = nombre;
                    jugadores[i].apellido = apellido;
                }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Cualquier duda escribe un comentario

Comment: como puedo hacer para que al modificar los datos el programa no finalice si no que vuelva a mostrar las opciones del menú, y después verificar que si se hallan modificado los datos @Alexci